# rendering a collection throws "htmlspecialchars() expects" how can I reder it like a Eloquent collection

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, collections, laravel-livewire

I call an API and put the response into a collection (thought it was a good idea) to reder it like a eloquent collection with a foreach in the blade

My trait:

```
class AzureRest
{
    public static function getSubscription($subscriptionId)
    {
        $token = TokenCache::getRestApiToken();
        $url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/".$subscriptionId."?api-version=2020-01-01";
        $json = Http::withToken($token)->get($url);
        return collect(json_decode($json, true, 5))->all();
    }
}
```

my livewire controller

```
class ShowSubscriptions extends Component
{
    public $subscriptionId;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->subscriptionId;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.azure.show-subscriptions',
        [
            'details' => AzureRest::getSubscription($this->subscriptionId)
        ]);
    }
}
```

my blade

```
<div>
    @foreach($details as $detail)
        <p>{{$detail->foo}}</p>
        <p>{{$detail->bar}}</p>
        <p>{{$detail->baz}}</p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

this is how the collection looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should better sleep more, I finally got it:

I removed the collection on the trait

```php
- return collect(json_decode($json, true, 5))->all();

+ return json_decode($json, true, 5);
```

and access the array as usual

```
        <p>{{$details['id']}}</p>
        <p>{{$details['displayName']}}</p>
        <p>{{$details['subscriptionPolicies']['spendingLimit']}}</p>
```

Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `all()` method in your collection, it returns the underlying array.

For example

```
collect([1, 2, 3])->all();
// [1, 2, 3] <--- returned
```

So when you try to do `$detail->foo`, it returns an error because it should really be `$detail['foo']` since it is returned as an array after doing `->all()`.

So try removing the `all()` and it should work.

Comment: I've tried this before but get the `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance` because I can't access the items